How much can you put into a sack?
The description of the sack says:

A sack can hold up to 1 cubic foot / 30 pounds of gear.1

A cubic foot of gold weighs over 1,188 pounds, equivalent to 59,400 gp. Can you carry it in the sack? Do both limits have to be observed at the same time, or can you fit in anything that fits under or up to each of these limits?

1 A typical real world sack of cement would have about 1 cubic foot of volume, but weigh close to 100 pounds. A sack of less dense dry goods would have been at least twice as large at 2 cubic feet, weighing around 100 to 200 pounds if filled, for example for sacks of flour, coal or salt. So even though it is mundane, the sack in the rules seems small, and able to carry much less weight than a normal, real-world sack would.

Following this logic, you can fit a 10-ft pole into a sack, since it weighs less than 30 pounds.

I don't think exclusive OR is used much in regular language.

I don't think you should be suprised by the fact that a real world cement sack can carry 4 times the weight of the one in the PHB. The former has been specifally designed by engineers over decades to be as durable as possible for its intended purpose, while the latter is just something a medieval peasant craftsman has stitched together.

I don't understand the point of this question.  It's not a magic sack.  The sack description is just there for convenience.  The DM can make up other sacks.  Real world sacks come in all shapes and sizes.

@Jack I think the point is "how are we to interpret the default values of this (or any other) container"

@TreeSpawned Yes. I just find the combination of these values together very restrictive and confusing because it does not at all match what I would expect a sack to be able to hold; but as the answers say, that is probably just how it is. Obviously one can make up other sacks, too.

@VLAZ I disagree. People use exclusive "or" in conversation all the time. In fact, without specifically researching it, I suspect people use the exclusive "or" in conversation more often than the logical, inclusive "or". We generally expect context to clarify which one we mean or use a lot more words when we must be absolutely unambiguous. As Shivers answered, in this case the context suggests that both criteria must be met for it to fit in a sack.

@enkryptor You are right on the 10-ft pole thing, this is a pretty obvious one. I could argue that the actual volume of the pole is probably less than 1 cubic foot, whatever the longest dimension is, but that gets even more nonsensical than not being able to hold more than 30 lbs

It needs to fit both
. . . as detailed in other answers.
Anything else is just silly.
Note what the Basic Rules actually says
In Container Capacity, the Sack entry says:

1 cubic foot/30 pounds of gear

There's no "or", there's just the slash.
The way I read it, it seems obvious to me that it means neither the volume nor the weight can be exceeded.
(Strange aside:  I swear when I looked, the D&D Beyond description when you just look up "sack" said "or", matching your quote, but checking now it has the slash.  One hypothesis is that someone at D&D Beyond reads rpg.se, looked themselves, saw the mismatch between the Basic Rules and the sack entry, and fixed it.  That's just crazy though.  I must have imagined it; only explanation.  Just for fun, though, I screenshotted the "barrel" and "bucket" entries, which had "or" when I screenshotted them.)
Also, I checked my physical Player's Handbook (wow it's been a long time since I actually opened the physical book), and its "Container Capacity" table has the slash.
What's the point of the "Container Capacity" table, anyway?
The beginning of the Equipment chapter in the Basic Rules says:

When you create your character, you receive equipment based on a combination of your class and background. Alternatively, you can start with a number of gold pieces based on your class and spend them on items from the lists in this section.

So, the stated purpose of the equipment lists are to give players a way to equip their characters.
So, if a player wants to equip their character with a sack, they can, and they know how much it costs, how much it weighs, and what it carries.  And they don't have to bother the DM.
Personally, I picture the player who says, "yeah, at 2 gp that backpack is too much for me, I'm just going to carry my stuff in a sack".
I think that it says "30 pounds of gear" supports that its provided as an alternative to a backpack, not some other kind of sack.
So the sack, (and the other containers) and all the other gear is just a default for equiping characters.
And, obviously, they had to have default capacities for all the containers.
But why those defaults?
We'll likely never know for sure.
I picture what a pillowcase would carry, though.
For that matter, the other containers are a bit strange.  For instance, a basket is:

2 cubic feet/40 pounds of gear

Clearly the basket is weaker than the sack . . . I guess.
I'll note that the AD&D Players Handbook offered both a large sack and a small sack, no capacities given.  I can't quite bring myself to research sacks through the editions, but maybe someone else will.
But it doesn't matter
If the player outfitting the character wants some other sack, or basket, or whatever, they can just ask the DM.
As we note over and over, D&D is not a real-world simulator.  The equipment lists aren't going to make perfect sense in every case (or any case?).  They just need to make enough sense to get a character built without the player pestering the DM over incredibly trivial stuff.  The player can just take the default from the list, and if the default doesn't work, and they really think it important, they can ask the DM.
The rules support almost any sack you might want
At the beginning of Chapter 5, Equipment, it says:

In the largest cities, almost anything imaginable is offered for sale, from exotic spices and luxurious clothing to wicker baskets and practical swords.

So if the player wants a different sack, ask the DM.  If the character wants a different sack, find a sack shop.

I'll accept this one -- because it provides a deeper exploration of the issues that are bothering me than the other answers, even though these of course have the same conclusion about what the rules text means.

@NobodytheHobgoblin  Where did you get your quote from, anyway?  I couldn't reproduce it with the "or".  Or rather, I think I did reproduce it with the "or", but I can't reproduce it again.

I looked up Sack on D&D Beyond.

There's a slash there now.

weird. Maybe it was one of the other, inoffical sites out there... not sure really. I think I checked it online. One I just checked that I'll not name had an "or" maybe it was from that one. My print version of the PHB also has the / language. I will update the question with the official text.

I swear they actually fixed it today.  What started my answer I looked at the "sack" definition and saw "or", and wondered where that entry was in the Basic Rules, and then saw the Container Capacities table.  Weird.

They are watching us ... nobody is safe. Our digital overlords...

I know, right?  D&D Beyond:  a) also note the Container Capacity table is missing the word "material" in 2 places in the BR and the PHB; b) clearly you need a copy editor; clearly I need things to edit; we should talk.  (I've been told I have an editing problem; not true, I can stop any time I want.)

It must fit both.
If you only have to meet one criteria, you have:

A bag that can hold 30lbs holding 1,188lbs because it can fit 1 cubic foot of gold.
A bag that can hold 1 cubic foot holding 12 cubic feet because it can fit an empty 25lb chest.

It simply doesn't make sense for this to be an either/or criteria. The rationale for the capacity of the sack comes down to developer intent, but I think you basically answered this in your question: the sack seems small because it is small, and it doesn't hold a ton of weight because it costs a single copper.

Both values define the limits of a container's usage
I think this question can be answered most easily if you think about what were to happen if you break either of those constraints:

Volume. If you put in more than a container's maximum volume, you won't be able to close it anymore and things will start to stick out of it at the top.
Weight. If you put in more than a container's maximum weight, it might start to get damaged or even break.

